# Strange time-related behavior issue prevents user access to server resources before 7am

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain

I need help.

My networking experience is limited to adding PC's to the domain and unlocking User accounts when they've miss-entered their password too many times.

Normally, we have everyone shutdown their PC's at night. Most people start work at either 7 am or 8 am, depending on their job. But we have at least 3 users that start earlier than that at between 5:30 am and 6 am.

The users that come in before 7am are unable to connect to our usual resources including SQLServer, or stock shares where our main app resides, nor our NAS drives which are part of a workgroup, nor the Internet itself until 7am every morning. After 7am everything starts working.

Needless to say it is driving us crazy. Part is the problem we are not sure what to look for. My shop consist of only my self and my boss and he's at his wit's end which is why he asked that I look into it for him.

If anyone has any ideas about what is going on, or how to discover what is going on, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: We can't answer this without knowing your topology. But in general you want to look for something critical that happens to be tied to a machine that gets started at 7 am. A server running (inappropriately) on someone's PC, for instance.

Comment: "OK Bob, flip on the DNS server." "Let me get some coffee first..."

Comment: My topology? Just a LAN. Our network uses 1 server running Win 2003 Server and SQL Server 2005, with about 25 workstations connected via routers, hubs and repeaters. Almost all connected PC's are part of a Domain. It is the only domain.

Comment: Can you set time limits on a DNS server such as lockout periods? Ryan, are you suggesting it may be getting turned off at sometime during the night and turns back on at 7 am?

Comment: This sounds very, very much like the domain server has user logon times limited. 

Perhaps take a look at the following settings: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816666

Comment: I'll take a look at that. We did have logon times limited to workhours, but they were supposedly removed by my boss. I've wondered if he missed a group's logon times.